# JSON syntax for getting personal query ID

Tags: json, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the following statement to get queries details out of TFS.
I can't find the way to get the details for query i have under "My Queries"
In TFS i have a query named: "Assigned to me" under the "My Queries" root.

Thank you!

I am using the following REST API syntax:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Under the GET section

Comment: What do you need? the query id? what do you try to achieve? the question not clear.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share some code or examples ...

Comment: Hi, i tried the syntax as in the documentation link i shared.
1st, tried to get my queries using: GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/queries/?name="Assigned To me"?api-version=5.0
i keep getting only the details for the root queries folders: "My Queries" And "Shared Queries" folders. I can't find a way to get the details for the queries under any of the folders.
2nd: once i get the query ID, get the results using: GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql/{id}?api-version=5.0

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this,you can use this [Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#query_by_name).

Sample Request:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/queries/My Queries/Assigned to me?api-version=5.0
```

**Note**:Hierarchical relationship of names in query conditions  e.g: **My Queries/Assigned to me**
[image]

Sample Response:
[image]
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your feedback!
However, it didn't work.....I am getting the following message:
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "TF401243: The query My Queries/Assigned to me does not exist, or you do not have permission to read it.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.QueryItems.QueryItemNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server",
    "typeKey": "QueryItemNotFoundException",
    "errorCode": 600288,
    "eventId": 3200
}
but the query does exist. I can see it thru TFS UI and see the records.

Comment: @Uzi Yona  please see my update, pay attention to the hierarchical relationship of the queries in your query condition. If there are other folders between your "assigned to me" query and "My Queries" query, you need to write the folder name in the query condition. e.g :My Queries/{folder name}/assigned to me

Comment: I think it has to something to do with the token i am using and permissions...i will need to check it and will update. Thank all for your help!

Comment: @Uzi Yona What's the result of your check?Has your problem been solved?